# button size and color changing

Tags: jquery, button, colors, size, toggle

i have here 4 buttons but only the first button is working, i want that the same jquery code a little bit changed to work on all these buttons...
i can copy past jquery 4 times and change it to work but i want more simple and less code with one jquery how to do it ?

**CSS**

```
.yellowBackground {    
    background-color: yellow;    
}

.redBackground {    
    background-color: red;
}

button.yellowBackground {    
    width:50px; 
    height:50px; 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td><button id="button"  class="yellowBackground">Pause</button></td>
      <td><button id="button"  class="yellowBackground">Pause</button></td>
      <td><button id="button"  class="yellowBackground">Pause</button></td>
      <td><button  id="button"  class="yellowBackground">Pause</button></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {    
    $("#button").click(function() {    
        changeThumb();    
    });    
});

function changeThumb() {    
    $("#button").toggleClass("redBackground");    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ID` must be Unique, you can also do this using class selector `yellowBackground` like below:

```
$(function() {
      $(".yellowBackground").click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("redBackground");
    });
 });
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/a221cu3b/)

Also you have missed opening `<tr>` tag inside your `<table>` html.Please correct that

Answer (score 0):

ID must be unique you can add handler to class `.yellowBackground` or to `button`

```
$(function() {

    $(".yellowBackground").click(function() {

        $(this).toggleClass("redBackground");

    });

});
```

Comment: thank you, i am new to this programming, somebody told me that we can only have one id but many classes.. how do i know that when to use class and when id?

Comment: you need use id when element is only one while class use when you have element repeat into the code :)

Comment: thank you now i got that, i tried to read about that 'this' but still dont know what is its job ? it refers to what ? if i change it to $(".yellowBackground") then it will make everything red...

Comment: refers to .yellowBackground clicked... yes if you change it to $(".yellowBackground") then it will make everything red

Comment: so what is 'this' if you want to explain it shortly
:D

Comment: Inside of a jQuery bound event function, this refers to the current DOM element from the collection which is being operated on. Since it is a DOM element, passing it to jQ like $( this ) makes it a jQuery collection so that you can do more jQuery stuff to it.

Comment: didn't get that but thank you i have disturbed you enough :D

Comment: don't worry i'm happy to help :)

Comment: :D can you tell me what is diferrence between these two this :  $(function() {
    $(".yellowBackground").click(function() {
        changeThumb();
   });

});

function changeThumb() {
    $(this).toggleClass("redBackground")
};
and this : $(function() {
      $(".yellowBackground").click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("redBackground");
    });
 });
        one is working other is not

Comment: first don't work because jquery can't understand what is this in the function, you need pass params with objects if you like it works..

Comment: but why now it understands ? : $(function() {
    $(".rond").click(function() {
        changeThumb();
  });

});

function changeThumb() {
    $("#button").toggleClass("redBackground")
};